# jQuery json client in VS2015

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2015

I can successfully run the html page below in notepad++, using the IE browser, to get a json file from my hosting service and display the data in a formatted fashion. It works just as it should.  However, I do have to click "allow blocked content" for it to work.  But, I'm unable to get the same html page to work in VS2015 - I'm trying to learn ASP.NET Core and using an empty template for this test.  I've tried the same test with a simple Web Site Project also with no luck.  I've been trying a number of different tutorials for json clients and keep running into the same problem where "data is undefined".  Is there some type of setting that I'm missing?

I have another Web API project that serves up json data and I can get that data using Postman with no problem.  However, I can't create my own web client to get that same data.  So, I'm trying to get this simple sample project working first to see if I can identify what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the data file on my hosting service:

```html
{
  "items": [
    {
      "key": "First",
      "value": 100
    },
    {
      "key": "Second",
      "value": false
    },
    {
      "key": "Last",
      "value": "Mixed"
    }
  ],
  "obj": {
    "number": 1.2345e-6,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "message": "Strings have to be in double-quotes."
}
​
```

This is the html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Request JSON Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="get-data">Get JSON data</a>
    <div id="show-data"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#get-data').click(function () {
                var showData = $('#show-data');

                $.getJSON('http://www.myHostingServer/test.json',
                    function (data) {
                        var items = data.items.map(function (item) {
                        return item.key + ': ' + item.value;
                    });
                    showData.empty();
                    if (items.length) {
                        var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
                        var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
                        showData.append(list);
                    }
                });
                showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: just to clarify, you are receiving a "allow blocked content" whenever getJson is executed?

Comment: "I can successfully run the html page below in notepad++." do you mean you create the page in notepad++ then open the page in a browser? you can't run it in notepad++ can you? when you run it from visual studio, you're opening a page that is on localhost?

Comment: When I create the page in VS and try to run it there in IE, I don't get the allow BC, but neither does it retrieve the data.  If I use the browser debugger, I can see the data undefined error along with a uri undefined error. If I create the page in notepad++ and run it there in IE, I get the proper result if I allow BC.  However, running it in notepad++ with any other browser doesn't work.  Just trying to run the page outside of notepad++ (from a folder on my PC) doesn't work either.  When I say it doesn't work, I mean I only get the "Loading" message - no data.

Comment: I should also note that the "pictures of Mount Rainier from the Flickr JSONP API." example from the jQuery API doc page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ - will run successfully from the same VS project that fails with the above example.  I've not been able to leverage the Flickr example with my own Web API project to retrieve data.  This is quite frustrating!

Comment: I put node on my PC and ran the above with the data file being local - works fine with that server.  The reason I put my data file on my hosting service is to eliminate problems with finding the file - there is only one URL to the hosting service file - which the notepad++ version found.  I mostly want to get at a data file or web api app on my PC.  Any suggestions for different ways to format the URL for a local datafile?